# Instalar Magento Community Edition no PHP 7.2.1

Tags: magento, php-7

Estou tentando instalar o Magento Community Edition 2.2.3 mas ele aparece o seguinte erro:
Your PHP version is 7.2.1. The required PHP version is 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0
Alguém sabe dizer se o Magento já tem suporte para essa versão do PHP ou se terei que fazer o downgrade da versão.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que fazer o `downgrade` do PHP. O Magento utiliza as funções `mcrypt` que foram deprecada no [PHP 7+](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral) e tornou-se obsoleta no PHP 7.2+, mas você ainda pode instalar via [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) e tentar executar.

Para instalar extensões via PECL, você terá que ter o `php-devel`, após instalala-lo, basta executar o comando abaixo no seu terminal.

```
pecl install "extname"
```

Feito isso, o PECL irá baixar o código fonte da extensão e depois compilará. Agora é só abrir seu `php.ini` e adicionar o conteúdo abaixo e depois reiniciar o PHP.

```
; Linux
extname.so

; Windows
extname.dll
```

Comment: Se eu instalar as extensões não precisarei fazer o downgrade??

Comment: Instalando a extensão, não precisa. Só será preciso alterar o `composer.json` do Magento